# RGoogleAnalytics Filtering Error

Tags: r, google-analytics

Hey guys so I have tried many different ways to do this query

```
        query.list <- Init(start.date = "2016-09-19",
                       end.date = "2016-09-23",
                       dimensions = "ga:date,ga:hour,ga:minute,ga:country",
                       metrics = "ga:newUsers",
                       filters = "ga:source!=Emai, ga:country==United Kingdom", 
                       max.results = 10000,
                       sort = "ga:date",
                       table.id = "ga:XXXX"
                       )
    ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)
    ga.data2 <- data.table(GetReportData(ga.query, token, split_daywise = T )

)
```

I do not know why it doesn't filter the country. I have tried only filtering the country and it simply does not work, I'm sure is something real simple that I'm missing. But I have tried every recommendation in other questions and is still not working. If I take out the country filter it works and if I put it does not do anything.. just outputs the same data

Comment: Why have you used slash `/` in `ga:source!=Email / ga:country==United Kingdom` ? you need to separate filter by a comma `,`

Comment: I have done that, still not working

Comment: oki so you want `AND` condition or `OR` condition between filters? Also have you checked creating the same report in GA ?

Comment: `AND` condition, the weird thing is that I use only the country filter and it doesn't work, and yes I have done the same report in GA and I'm having the desired results

Comment: oki so here you go... please use semicolon `;` for `AND` condition. Next you need to encode the `==` . so the filter would be :` `ga:source!=Email;ga:country%3D%3DUnited%20Kingdom`

Comment: when I use only `ga:country==United Kingdom` I get the following error message:
_Error in GetDataFeed(query.uri) : 
  no loop for break/next, jumping to top level_

Comment: Encode the space between United and kingdom as well. Its a common issue `ga:source!=Email;ga:country%3D%3DUnited%20Kingdom`

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: I am posting it as an answer. Please accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to include `AND` operator, which is denoted by a semicolon `;`. Moreover, you need to URL encode all the parameters in the filter, so the correct filter would be:

```
ga:source!=Email;ga:country%3D%3DUnited%20Kingdom
```

---

**To all readers**:

While building the query in R for core reporting, `please make sure that all the values are URL encoded`. If you feel any difficulty in encoding, you can build the query from [Google's Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)